# How can I add the to_string() functionality to an enum?

Tags: string, error-handling, rust, traits

I am trying to create `Error` enums that implement `to_string()`. I have tried to `derive(Debug)` for them but it doesn't seem to be enough.

Here is the enum that I am working on:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum InnerError {
    InnerErrorWithDescription(String),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum OuterError {
    OuterErrorWithDescription(String),
}
```

What I am trying to make is:

```
// result type <T,InnerErrorWithDescription>
result.map_err(|err| { Error::OuterErrorWithDescription(err.to_string())}) // .to_string() is not available
```

I could not manage to convert `InnerError` enum type to `OuterError`.

What should I change to implement it?

I have made an example for writing enum types and their values' here:

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6a3c4a17c3c28d7c571e221440ac197c&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

But, still I had to specify the type and it's description in match case, are there any more generic implementation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your enum should implement [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html); from [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html) docs:

> This trait is automatically implemented for any type which implements
>   the `Display` trait. As such, `ToString` shouldn't be implemented
>   directly: `Display` should be implemented instead, and you get the
>   `ToString` implementation for free.

Edit: I have adjusted your playground example; I think you might be after something [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e64aacfacd620c5a12466ba556c49606&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).

Comment: This example is useful, but still we need to specify the to_string description as hardcoded. Can we make a dynamically generated string description containing the enum type and the description of it inside of the formatter? I am looking for something like: write!(f,"{} , {} ",self.type,self.desc)

Comment: @AkinerAlkan in that case you might be interested in an error struct rather than an enum: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=488a9117d81e61b5ae02afed538b11d1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).